# How to use perf or any profiling tool for finding the cpu-cycle or amount of cpu utilized by the functions of my application or program

Tags: c, profiling, yocto, perf, oprofile

Hi I am trying to use perf on a yocto system. When I do perf record ./applicaton I get this data

```
Children      Self  Command     Shared Object               Symbol
+   37.50%    37.50%  application  libc-2.26.so                [.] _int_malloc
+    9.27%     9.27%  application  libc-2.26.so                [.] memset
+    5.71%     0.00%  application  [unknown]                   [.] 00000000
+    3.79%     0.00%  udevd       [unknown]                   [.] 00000000
```

since I have two functions in my code functiona and functionb which is been called by main.c.
I need the profiling should be more specific to those two functions like

```
Children      Self  Command     Shared Object               Symbol
+   37.50%    37.50%  application  functiona                [.] _int_malloc
+    9.27%     9.27%  application  functionb               [.] memset
```

something like that. How can I get that using perf tool or oprofile tool

Comment: Use --call-graph to get the whole call stack

Comment: Hi jussi I tried that too but it still doesn't give me function names of my functions. if you see that + sign under children column it enables the call graph I still get the functions which could be in the kernel level. I don't see the names of my functions anywhere in it. I did perf record -g ./application for it. and to check per report --call-graph perf.data

Comment: If you use a recipe for your app, you'll probably need to include `<app>-dbg` package? Personnally I use `valgrind` and `gperftools` for profiling.